# Why am I unable to allocate space using malloc in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I have the following function:

```
int* getDifference(char* s1, char* s2){
    int* difference = (int*) malloc(sizeof(s1) / sizeof(s1[0]) * sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s1); ++i){
        difference[i] = (s1[i] - s2[i] + 26) % 26;
    }
    return difference;
}
```

If I try to call it using:

```
char* encryptedSignature = "hello";
char* signature = "volvo";
int* key = getDifference(encryptedSignature, signature);
free(key);
```

It results in the following error on runtime:

> /bin/sh: line 1: 10508 Segmentation fault: 11  ./code < input001.txt
>   make: *** [code] Error 139

Why does this happen? Is there another way this should be done?

**EXTRA:**

If I use Sublime Text to build, I get:

> code(10470,0x7fffdf5f83c0) malloc: *** error for object
>   0x7fea1d402648: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was
>   probably modified after being freed.
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug /bin/sh: line 1: 10470 Abort trap: 6           ./code < input001.txt make: *** [code]
>   Error 134

Comment: `sizeof(s1) / sizeof(s1[0])` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @WeatherVane it _is_ a duplicate. There must be a 100 of them around

Comment: The mantra is: "*Pointers are not arrays, and arrays are not pointers.*"